# EF Core Updates Seeded Data on every Migration without being changed

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

So I'm seeding my databse with Users and Roles like this.

```
public static void SeedUsers(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var roles = new[]
        {
            new Role
            {
                Id = new Guid("5127599a-e956-4f5e-9385-1b8c6a74e4f1"),
                RoleName = "Customer"
            },
            new Role
            {
                Id = new Guid("8634c476-20fa-4391-b8f7-8713abf61af0"),
                RoleName = "Admin"
            }
        };

        // customer password
        byte[] customerPasswordHash = null;
        byte[] customerPasswordSalt = null;
        HashPassword("asd123", out customerPasswordHash, out customerPasswordSalt);

        // admin password
        byte[] adminPasswordHash = null;
        byte[] adminPasswordSalt = null;
        HashPassword("asd123", out adminPasswordHash, out adminPasswordSalt);
        var users = new[]
        {
            new Users()
            {
                Id = new Guid("3b86f5a2-1978-46e3-a0b6-edbb6b558efc"),
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe",
                DepositedCash = 10000,
                Email = "john@doe.com",
                RoleId = roles[0].Id,
                PasswordHash = customerPasswordHash,
                PasswordSalt = customerPasswordSalt
            },
            new Users()
            {
                Id = new Guid("c643b944-53d9-4a0c-9922-3486558b9129"),
                FirstName = "Admin",
                LastName = "Admin",
                DepositedCash = 10000,
                Email = "admin@admin.com",
                RoleId = roles[1].Id,
                PasswordHash = adminPasswordHash,
                PasswordSalt = adminPasswordSalt
            }
        };

        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>()
            .HasData(roles);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
            .HasData(users);
    }

    private static void HashPassword(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
    {
        using (var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("predefined key")))
        {
            passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
            passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        }
    }
```

I'm creating a migration and Update the database. So far so good.

After that when I create another test migration, without changing anything it creates an UpdateData method with the same data. Everything in `Up` and `Down` methods is the same.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace Pizzeria.Data.Migrations
{
public partial class test : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
            table: "Users",
            keyColumn: "Id",
            keyValue: new Guid("3b86f5a2-1978-46e3-a0b6-edbb6b558efc"),
            columns: new[] { "PasswordHash", "PasswordSalt" },
            values: new object[] { new byte[] { 211, 141, 232, 166, 77, 237, 128, 211, 121, 45, 47, 68, 211, 202, 162, 3, 39, 214, 212, 153, 4, 199, 223, 213, 43, 233, 224, 21, 107, 10, 62, 220, 105, 27, 254, 137, 16, 208, 56, 42, 254, 211, 154, 27, 60, 135, 197, 224, 148, 99, 232, 246, 220, 121, 113, 103, 42, 117, 172, 240, 134, 14, 188, 25 }, new byte[] { 112, 114, 101, 100, 101, 102, 105, 110, 101, 100, 32, 107, 101, 121 } });

        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
            table: "Users",
            keyColumn: "Id",
            keyValue: new Guid("c643b944-53d9-4a0c-9922-3486558b9129"),
            columns: new[] { "PasswordHash", "PasswordSalt" },
            values: new object[] { new byte[] { 211, 141, 232, 166, 77, 237, 128, 211, 121, 45, 47, 68, 211, 202, 162, 3, 39, 214, 212, 153, 4, 199, 223, 213, 43, 233, 224, 21, 107, 10, 62, 220, 105, 27, 254, 137, 16, 208, 56, 42, 254, 211, 154, 27, 60, 135, 197, 224, 148, 99, 232, 246, 220, 121, 113, 103, 42, 117, 172, 240, 134, 14, 188, 25 }, new byte[] { 112, 114, 101, 100, 101, 102, 105, 110, 101, 100, 32, 107, 101, 121 } });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
            table: "Users",
            keyColumn: "Id",
            keyValue: new Guid("3b86f5a2-1978-46e3-a0b6-edbb6b558efc"),
            columns: new[] { "PasswordHash", "PasswordSalt" },
            values: new object[] { new byte[] { 211, 141, 232, 166, 77, 237, 128, 211, 121, 45, 47, 68, 211, 202, 162, 3, 39, 214, 212, 153, 4, 199, 223, 213, 43, 233, 224, 21, 107, 10, 62, 220, 105, 27, 254, 137, 16, 208, 56, 42, 254, 211, 154, 27, 60, 135, 197, 224, 148, 99, 232, 246, 220, 121, 113, 103, 42, 117, 172, 240, 134, 14, 188, 25 }, new byte[] { 112, 114, 101, 100, 101, 102, 105, 110, 101, 100, 32, 107, 101, 121 } });

        migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
            table: "Users",
            keyColumn: "Id",
            keyValue: new Guid("c643b944-53d9-4a0c-9922-3486558b9129"),
            columns: new[] { "PasswordHash", "PasswordSalt" },
            values: new object[] { new byte[] { 211, 141, 232, 166, 77, 237, 128, 211, 121, 45, 47, 68, 211, 202, 162, 3, 39, 214, 212, 153, 4, 199, 223, 213, 43, 233, 224, 21, 107, 10, 62, 220, 105, 27, 254, 137, 16, 208, 56, 42, 254, 211, 154, 27, 60, 135, 197, 224, 148, 99, 232, 246, 220, 121, 113, 103, 42, 117, 172, 240, 134, 14, 188, 25 }, new byte[] { 112, 114, 101, 100, 101, 102, 105, 110, 101, 100, 32, 107, 101, 121 } });
    }
}
}
```

Why it updates the Users without any change ? What am I missing ?

Comment: I didn't test it, but I think it's because of the pregenerated salt and password. On every new reference or change in properties new migration is created.

Comment: In my case it was setting a DateTime property of entity to Datetime.Now. Of course it was different every time...

Comment: @DiPi you should promote this comment as an answer! Any data added via HasData has to be reliably deterministic and unchanging between migrations in order to prevent its reappearance in subsequent migrations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to seed with the raw value to avoid this :

```
var users = new[]
        {
            new Users()
            {
                Id = new Guid("3b86f5a2-1978-46e3-a0b6-edbb6b558efc"),
                FirstName = "John",
                LastName = "Doe",
                DepositedCash = 10000,
                Email = "john@doe.com",
                RoleId = roles[0].Id,
                PasswordHash = new byte[] { 211, 141, 232, 166, 77, 237, 128, 211, 121, 45, 47, 68, 211, 202, 162, 3, 39, 214, 212, 153, 4, 199, 223, 213, 43, 233, 224, 21, 107, 10, 62, 220, 105, 27, 254, 137, 16, 208, 56, 42, 254, 211, 154, 27, 60, 135, 197, 224, 148, 99, 232, 246, 220, 121, 113, 103, 42, 117, 172, 240, 134, 14, 188, 25 },
                PasswordSalt = new byte[] { 112, 114, 101, 100, 101, 102, 105, 110, 101, 100, 32, 107, 101, 121 }
            },
            new Users()
            {
                Id = new Guid("c643b944-53d9-4a0c-9922-3486558b9129"),
                FirstName = "Admin",
                LastName = "Admin",
                DepositedCash = 10000,
                Email = "admin@admin.com",
                RoleId = roles[1].Id,
                PasswordHash = new byte[] { 211, 141, 232, 166, 77, 237, 128, 211, 121, 45, 47, 68, 211, 202, 162, 3, 39, 214, 212, 153, 4, 199, 223, 213, 43, 233, 224, 21, 107, 10, 62, 220, 105, 27, 254, 137, 16, 208, 56, 42, 254, 211, 154, 27, 60, 135, 197, 224, 148, 99, 232, 246, 220, 121, 113, 103, 42, 117, 172, 240, 134, 14, 188, 25 },
                PasswordSalt = new byte[] { 112, 114, 101, 100, 101, 102, 105, 110, 101, 100, 32, 107, 101, 121 }
            }
        };
```

That way EF Core will generate a migration knowing this is a fixed value and will not update it in every migration. Using a method (HashPassword here) prevent EF Core from considering it as fixed.