# Why does EF Core update seeded boolean fields on every migration, despite no changes being made?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-3.1

This is EF Core 3.1. I have several models with a boolean field, `IsActive`, defined like so:

```cs
public class Job
{
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

My seed data looks like this:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
    .Property(e => e.IsActive)
    .HasDefaultValue(true);

modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().HasData(
    new Job() { IsActive = true });
```

Every time I create a migration (including if I run a migration with no changes made, which should generate an empty migration), it has a `UpdateData` call for the field above, like so:

```cs
migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
    table: "Jobs",
    keyColumn: "id",
    keyValue: 1L,
    column: "IsActive",
    value: true);
```

I've also replicated this behavior in the [TodoApi app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio-code) and [setup a GitHub repo](https://github.com/kadams54/TodoApi) for anyone interested in more details.

I understand [that happening when the seed data is being generated by a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55151895/ef-core-updates-seeded-data-on-every-migration-without-being-changed?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C34.6996), or the result of something like `DateTime.Now`. I don't understand it happening here, when the column is assigned a raw boolean value during seeding.

This behavior seems very similar to [issue #13047](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13047), "Incorrect UpdateData operations generated when using BoolToStringConverter with HasData", but that issue [was fixed in EF Core 2.2](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/12712).

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your case. Could you share complete seeding code for 1 entity? And also what exactly changed in your models that caused the new migration?

Comment: I've updated the question with more details, including a link to a GH repo where I've replicated the behavior in a simple app. I also included the complete seeding data and clarified that this happens even in migrations that ought to be empty (e.g., nothing changed).

Comment: It's the default value. Just added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the reason is the `HasDefaultValue(true)` call in the following model configuration code -

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>()
    .Property(e => e.IsActive)
    .HasDefaultValue(true);
```

Whenever you set a default value for a property with the `HasDefaultValue()` method, **that** is the value to be set for the respective column in the database table.

With `HasDefaultValue(true)`, you have set `true` to be the default value for `IsActive` property. Therefore, in the seed data -

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Job>().HasData(
    new Job() { IsActive = true });
```

setting a value to `IsActive` (doesn't matter whatever the value is) is a change from migration's perspective, even though the data didn't change between migrations.

**EDIT - What is the solution:**
The requirement to set default value for a column is always a valid requirement. So the other thing you might consider to change is the data seeding approach.

The seeding approach you are using now is completely managed by migrations itself, and it has some limitations - [Limitations of model seed data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#limitations-of-model-seed-data)

You can use a [Custom initialization logic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#custom-initialization-logic) to seed data which migrations has nothing to do with.

Comment: So is there any way to define default values at the DB level such that I won't end up with a bunch of no-op statements in every migration? For the time being, I've removed `IsActive = true` from all the seed data, but I do have some records that are `IsActive = false`.

Comment: Also, you can/should report an issue on EF's GitHub  repo describing your specific scenario.The migrations-managed seeding was the latest by EF-team and as the limitation section implies, one of the scenarios where you should consider custom initialization logic is when you are seeding temporary data for testing. But you can always have to set a default value while _not_ seeding temporary data.